# Print passed variable name in funciton parameter argument as string (Swift)

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a function called `printValue(_ variable: Double)`.
Here is how I want to call it in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   print("viewDidLoad starts here")
   let poisitionX: Double = 5.7
   printValue(positionX)
}
```

What should I write inside my function in order to print both the passed variable name

```
func printValue(_ variable: Double) {
   //convert passed variable name to string
   let str = /*..how?..*/ 

   print(str, "=", String(variable))
}
```

When I run the project, I want to see the following in the Target Output console in Xcode:

> viewDidLoad starts here

> positionX = 5.7

Comment: That is not how variables work or should work. The nested method cannot and should not know the name of the parameter in the outer scope. What happens if I call it via `printValue(3.7)`, what name should be printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for `printValue` func to know that you passed a value named `positionX` because `printValue` knows only about a variable named `variable`.
What you could do is changing the `printValue` func passing also the variable name as a `String`. E.g:

```swift
func printValue(_ value: Double, _ name: String) {
   print("\(name) = \(value)")
}
```

and call it like:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   print("viewDidLoad starts here")
   let poisitionX: Double = 5.7
   printValue(positionX, "positionX")
}
```